# One of my variables will 'update' but immediately gets reset to zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a points managing script to add up all the points a player gets while playing. Points come from collectables, or killing enemies. The specific functions are called from different scripts. The collectables side of things work just fine, but all of the enemy points do not work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class PointsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float collectionPoints;
    public float killPoints;
    public float totalPoints;
    public TextMeshProUGUI pointsDisplay;

    void Start()
    {
        collectionPoints = 0.0f;
        killPoints = 0.0f;
        totalPoints = 0.0f;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    public void CollectGear()
    {
        collectionPoints += 5.0f;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    public void CollectMetal()
    {
        collectionPoints += 25.0f;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    public void KillLeveOneEnemy()
    {
        killPoints += 25.0f;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    public void KillLeveTwoEnemy()
    {
        killPoints += 50.0f;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    public void KillLeveThreeEnemy()
    {
        killPoints += 150.0f;
        UpdatePoints();
    }

    private void UpdatePoints()
    {
        Debug.Log("Collection" + collectionPoints + "killPoints" + killPoints);
        totalPoints = collectionPoints + killPoints;
        pointsDisplay.SetText("Points" + totalPoints);
    }
}
```

I have made sure that all the functions get called, and that `killPoints` is updated correctly as I can see the debug message in the console with the correct amount of points, but when the text is displayed the `killPoints` are set to zero, and thus the `totalPoints` are off.

Comment: Make your public fields private. Now someone from outside can change them.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that will do what you describe so it probably is being set from the outside. If you need to access the values from outside, make them properties and make the setters private.

Comment: Setting the public fields to private is a good idea, but nothing changed.

Comment: The code for collecting gears and coins works just fine. The code that gives you points for killing enemies does not. And the code runs, and it updates the 'killpoints' but when  it adds it to the total points it gets reset to zero

Comment: As others have said. No code here does that. So. Either this point manager is in multiple places. So each one is zero. Or something else is doing it.

Comment: Consider adding debug messages at every spot where the points are changed. A general possibility here is that your `Start()` method is called again, or that the entire manager object is recreated.